# Room migration and internal file loss

Tags: android, kotlin, database-migration, android-room

I need to move some files around for my app's next update. These "files" are composed mainly of JPEGs that are being tracked by a dedicated table in my database. Based on that fact, I've decided to use a `Migration` object to handle both database migration and file relocation.

A simplified snippet of my `Migration` class:

```
class VersionOneToTwo(private val appDataDir: File) : Migration(1, 2) {

    override fun migrate(database: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
        database.beginTransaction()
        try {
            renameUriColumnInMedia(database)
            updatePathDataInMedia(database)
            moveEntryPhotoFilesToNewFolder(appDataDir)
            database.setTransactionSuccessful()
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            throw MigrationFailed(1, 2, e)
        } finally {
            database.endTransaction()
        }
    }

    private fun renameUriColumnInMedia(database: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
        database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE media RENAME TO old_media ...")
        database.execSQL("CREATE TABLE `media` ...")
        database.execSQL("INSERT INTO `media` ...")
        database.execSQL("DROP TABLE old_media ...")
    }

    private fun updatePathDataInMedia(database: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
        database.execSQL("UPDATE media SET `path` = REPLACE(`path`, '/Photos/', '/entry-photos/') ...")
    }

    private fun moveEntryPhotoFilesToNewFolder(appDataDir: File) {
        moveFiles(File(appDataDir, "Photos"), File(appDataDir, "entry-photos"))
    }

    private fun moveFiles(sourceDir: File, targetDir: File) {
        if (sourceDir.exists().not()) {
            // This operation is not necessary.
            return
        }
        if (sourceDir.isDirectory.not()) {
            throw IllegalArgumentException("The given source directory is not a valid directory.")
        }

        if (targetDir.mkdirs().not()) {
            throw IOException("The creation of target directory has failed.")
        }

        sourceDir.listFiles().forEach {
            val movedFile = File(targetDir, it.name)
            it.copyTo(movedFile, true)
        }

        sourceDir.deleteRecursively()
    }
}
```

The crazy thing is, everytime it gets to the point of actually moving the files (when `moveEntryPhotoFilesToNewFolder()` gets called) my files seem to have gone missing:

- `sourceDir.exists()` in `moveEntryPhotoFilesToNewFolder()` returned `false`
- `sourceDir.listFiles()` in the same method returned `null`
- `adb shell; run-as <mypackage>; ls files;`printed out nothing

I've tried to comment-out the file relocation part of the migration and sure enough my app would run. The files would still be missing though.

Have I missed something obvious here? I checked and double checked; no other code in my project ever call `delete()` nor `deleteRecursively()` outside of that `Migration` class I've shown above.

---

p.s., `appDataDir` here is `Context.getFilesDir()`